# Repeated selections

Tags: angular

I fetched data from database to mat-select. So I user can choose 4 defenders to his team, so defenders are fetched from database for 4 mat-select. But user can choose same player in this 4 mat-select and I want to protect this.

It is see this:

Here you can see choices to select one defender
[image: select players]

In second select you can choose from same defenders, but if user select same defender like before one select, system allow this him. But I don´t know.
[image: repeated selections]

What is about my code, here is part of my HTML:

HTML:

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoading"></mat-spinner>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="onSaveUserTeam()" *ngIf="!isLoading">

    <h3>Name: </h3>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="UserTeam name">
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('name').invalid">Please enter a userTeam name.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

   <h3>Goalkeeper: </h3>
  <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="Goalkeepers" formControlName="goalkeeper">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let player of goalkeepers" [value]="player.id">
        {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)

        {{sumPrice(userTeam.badget,player.price)}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
  <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('goalkeeper').invalid">Pleasse enter a goalkeeper.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

    <h3>Goalkeeper substitution: </h3>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="Goalkeepers sub" formControlName="goalkeeper_sub">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let player of goalkeepers" [value]="player.id">
              {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)

              {{sumPrice(userTeam.badget,player.price)}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
     <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('goalkeeper_sub').invalid">Please enter a userTeam goalkeeper_sub.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <h3>Defender: </h3>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="defender1" formControlName="defender1">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let player of defenders" [value]="player.id">
              {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
     <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('defender1').invalid">Please enter a userTeam defender1.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <h3>Defender: </h3>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select placeholder="defender2" formControlName="defender2">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let player of defenders" [value]="player.id">
              {{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.price}}M)
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
     <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('defender2').invalid">Please enter a userTeam defender2.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</mat-card>
```

And TS file:
Part code of validations:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({

      name: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      goalkeeper: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      goalkeeper_sub: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      defender1: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      defender2: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
```

And Save Team:

```
onSaveUserTeam() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.isLoading = true;
    if (this.mode === "create") {
        this.userTeamsService.addUserTeam(
        this.form.value.name,
        this.form.value.badget,

        this.form.value.goalkeeper,
        this.form.value.goalkeeper_sub,

        this.form.value.defender1,
        this.form.value.defender2,
        this.form.value.defender3,
        this.form.value.defender4,
      );
```

Can you give me advice, how can I protect this problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: Write a validator that checks that no two identical defenders have been selected, and add it to the form group: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-reactive-forms-1

Comment: Why not using the multi select?

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) 
Talg123 - because one select mean one position. Or multi select is easier to use in this case?